# How can i store string value with whitespace in char array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, replaceall

Looking this code

```
        String input="I use this method";
        String word=input.replaceAll(" ","/");
        char buf[]=word.toCharArray();
```

but i want to another method to doing this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say you want another method?

Comment: another way to doing this

Comment: Why would you want to reinvent the wheel? This is literally as simple as it gets.

Comment: in here i replace  '/'  for whitespace but i want store white space directly

Comment: So, store whitespace directly. Why are you even doing the replace?

Comment: because i don't know store whitespace directly in char array

Comment: "*another way to doing this*" how about instead of `replaceAll(" ","/")` use `replace(" ","/")`, or maybe even `replace(' ', '/')`? But seriously, you need to [edit] your question and include more informations about what you want to achieve. Some examples of input and expected output would also be nice.

Comment: I asked the question beginner for java  since the day when i asked the question finally i got it .this can be done easily using this code   `String word="I use this method" ;`   `char buf []=word.toCharArray();`        this is way  to store  white space in char array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the easiest way I have found to convert a string including white spaces to a char array in java.

```
String input = "I use this method";
char[] buf = input.toCharArray();
```

It looks like you are doing it right, but taking out all of the white space with the `replaceAll(" ", "/")`

Answer (score 1):

From your question I'm assuming you want to save the string without truncating the whitespace in a char array.

If your remove the line " **String word=input.replaceAll(" ","/");** " from your code.Then your code will work perfectly fine.PFB  a sample code which might help you to understand this better

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
       String input="I use this method";
       System.out.println(input.length()); //length of string before converting to char array
       //String word=input.replaceAll(" ","/");
       char buf[]=input.toCharArray();
       System.out.println(buf.length);//length of string after converting to char array
       for(int i=0;i<buf.length;i++){
       System.out.print(buf[i]); /// Print the values in char array
       }
  }
```